# No module named 'fcntl', while attempting to install Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, fcntl

I wanted to install Pyinstaller to distribute a python script of mine, without needing to share the source code. From what I've seen online, fcntl is a Linux library, which is rather strange, since Pyinstaller is used to make .exe files, which are run on Windows. The following is the error I got while using `pip install pyinstaller`.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Note: I haven't included the complete error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: pyinstaller is not _just_ for Windows; it can package executables for other platforms as well. Anyhow -- the `fcntl` import is not part of pyinstaller itself when you're running it on Windows; it's coming from the program you're trying to package or one of its library dependencies (possibly on account of pyinstaller not properly detecting that an import takes place only on non-Windows platforms). We'd need a [mre] to be able to describe exactly which dependency or otherwise how it's getting into your dependency chain.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if we're talking about libraries, I used Pygame, and Sys. However, while issuing the command `pip install pyinstaller`, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The fcntl module is not available on Windows. The functionality it exposes does not exist on that platform.

You can use an alternative like **portalocker** module. After some research, I found out that the substitute of fcntl on windows are **win32api** calls.

Comment: How do I install win32api? I am trying to package my .py file into an exe, not trying to lock my files